# run vue dev server gitlab-ci and microservice architecture

Tags: npm, jestjs, gitlab-ci, end-to-end

My goal is to set up CI on gitlab. My project consists of 5 different services, details are unimportant. I have tests written which I currently run locally by running a terminal `npm run dev` and in a second terminal `npm run test` all whist in other terminals the remaining 4 services are run similarly using `npm run dev`/`npm start`. I am using gitlab-runner ssh executor (although I would be open to try others) I would like to be able to deploy the dev server and run my jest tests in my pipeline with the dependent projects running. After the tests have completed initiated from a single service, I would like the other dependent services to be brought down gracefully.

I have thought about issuing `npm run dev` as a background process `nohup` and using `nc` to await a response on the port, something like `while ! nc -w 1 -z localhost 3000; do sleep 0.1; done` however I don't think that would be best practice, as well as the issue of killing the initial `npm run dev` process after the tests have run. I would also use the same technique for bringing up the other dependent services.
Another idea was to use `Jest` `beforeAll()` to setup the dev server and `afterAll()` to tear it down (along with dependent services), is there a method to programmatically deploy the nuxt development server and express servers?

The question is; how should this best be achieved? By my suggested methods or ones I haven't come across yet.
It would be good to use gitlabs pipeline triggers to deploy the other dependent services but my question there would be - if I use the first method to run the dev servers in the background, how can I keep these up and running until the tests from the upstream pipeline finish?

Some extra bits:

in my package.json:

```json
...
"scripts": {
  "dev": "nuxt",
  "test": "jest"
}
```

Example of `.gitlab-ci.yml` - this of course hangs at `npm run dev`.

```yaml
deployNuxt:
  stage: build
  tags:
    - test
  before_script:
    - export PATH=$PATH:/home/[user]/.nvm/versions/node/v13.12.0/bin
  script:
    - npm install
    - npm run dev
    - npm run test
```

If I were to use pipeline API, it would look like:

```yaml
stages:
  - Trigger-cross-projects
  - build

deployAuth:
  stage: Trigger-cross-projects
  tags:
    - test
  script:
    - "curl -X POST -F token=[token] -F ref=[ref_name] [pipeline api endpoint]"
deployNuxt:
  stage: build
  tags:
    - test
  before_script:
    - export PATH=$PATH:/home/[user]/.nvm/versions/node/v13.12.0/bin
  script:
    - npm install
    - npm run dev
    - npm run test
```

```
Architecture (separate git projects):
service 1 - nuxt (frontend)    <---- this is where the tests are run
service 2 - express server (backend)
service 3 - authentication
service 4 - gateway
```

Relevant question and answer regarding starting processes with `nohup` (bare in mind I'm looking for best practice here though, and how to keep dependent services running during tests): https://stackoverflow.com/a/56857336/3770935